# Is an initializer list static enough to allow instantiating templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compile-time-constant, stdinitializerlist

I apologize for the badly formed question. I wasn't sure how to ask it.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int V>
void output() {
  std::cout << V << "\n";
}

int main() {

  output<1>(); // this works
  output<2>();

  for (int v : {1,2,3} ) {
    output<v>(); // this not
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I thought having a finite number of iterations would be enough to make that templated function instantiated, but no.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: You would need something like `for (constexpr int v : {1,2,3} )` which is not part of the language.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that.  However, the problem isn't that `std::initializer_list` isn't constant enough.  It doesn't work because you can't have `output<>()` change types on each iteration of the loop.

An initializer list can be `constexpr`, and a `constexpr` value can be used as a non-type template parameter.  For example, these all work:

```
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> x{10, 20};
output<x.size()>();
output<*x.begin()>();
constexpr const int& ref = *x.begin();
output<ref>();
```

In your code, `v` is not `constexpr`. It changes on each iteration of the loop.  So it can't be used as a non-type template parameter.

To summarize, an `std::initialier_list<>`, the size of a such a list, and a *specific* element of the list, are all constant enough to be non-type template parameters.  A reference to elements in the list, which changes on each iteration of a loop, is not constant enough.

You will find that nothing which changes on each iteration of a loop is constant enough.  In the same manner, an `auto` variable in loop that is intended to change types between iterations is also not possible.

Integer constant expressions and types can only change between instantiations of a templated object or function.  On each instantiation of the template they have a value fixed for the entire scope of the object/function being instantiated.  They can not change between iterations of a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <int ... Vs>
void output_many() {
    (output<Vs>(),...);
}

output_many<1, 2, 3>();
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/MFLUY67122)

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question!